# Bind mount docker with specific user and permission

Tags: docker, docker-compose

*Scenario*
I want to use Docker in Docker as per [this guide](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

The key point is that you'll need to bind mount the Docker socket from host machine into the Docker socket inside the container in order to use Docker from inside the container.

*Issue*
The Docker socket on the host machine is always bind mounted into Docker container under root:root. When I execute the container as a non-root user, executing Docker commands gives permission denied.

*Question*
How to bind mount a file from host into Docker container with specific user:group and permission?

Comment: StackOverflow has closed this question so I can't reply properly (and I think it's a bit silly for me to edit your question just to answer it myself) so I'll just post the answer I've found to work here: add the argument `-u 1000:988` to your `docker run` command, this adds your user to the `docker` group (which has permission to interact with the mounted socket). Tested in Jenkins in EC2, you might need a different GID to `988` in a different environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can workaround that:

set the group permission on the file to `ID` not exists on the `host`, and give the group full access:

```
chown :999 /path/to/file
chmod 775 /path/to/file
chmod g+s /path/to/file
```

then on your Dockerfile add the `group` and assign the `user` to it:

```
RUN addgroup --gid 999 GROUPNAME 
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --force-badname --ingroup 999 USERNAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if I set the file to some non-existing ID on host machine, the file (docker socket) will become unusable on host machine. So this doesn't work for me.

Comment: no it will still usable, the owner will still the root

Comment: Guess I'll try that. But I still want to look for an option that does not require me to modify the file on host machine at all. The idea is that I should be able to just start the container from the docker-compose file and be able to use it. Modifying the file in host machine seems like adhoc solution to me and is an extra step must be done separately.